# How to make table in reactjs looks good

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-applications, tailwind-css

So i have a schooltask to make a table with ReactJs. i made the table but it need to look better but idk how to modify my code to make like i want, look on youtube but the design i want usually they download from somewhere which i haven't understand yet. Here my  table looks like now [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARlvi.png). But i want the design look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nubo.jpg). Btw i using Tailwindcss tools. here's my code about my table

App.js (My input on the table) :

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./App.css"; 
import data from  "./dataset.json";
import Header from "./Header";



const App = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(data);
  
   
  
   
    return ( 
      
         <div className="app-container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>NAMA</th>
                    <th>UMUR</th>
                    <th>TINGGI</th>
                    <th>BERAT BADAN</th>
                    <th>JENIS KELAMIN</th>
                    <th>TEKANAN SISTOLE</th>
                    <th>TEKANAN DIASTOLE</th>
                    <th>TINGKAT KOLESTEROL</th>
                    <th>TINGKAT GLUKOSA</th>
                    <th>PEROKOK AKTIF/TIDAK</th>
                    <th>ALKOHOLIK/TIDAK</th>
                    <th>AKTIVITAS FISIK</th>
                    <th>RIWAYAT PENYAKIT CARDIOVASCULAR</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {contacts.map((contacts)=> (
                <tr>
                  <td>{contacts.name}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.age}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.height}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.weight}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.gender ? "Laki-laki" : "Perempuan"}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.ap_hi}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.ap_lo}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.cholestrol}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.gluc}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.smoke ? "Aktif" :  "Tidak Aktif"}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.alco ? "Aktif" :  "Tidak Aktif"}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.active ? "Aktif" :  "Tidak Aktif"}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.cardio ? "Ada" :  "Tidak Ada"}</td>
                </tr>

              )
              
              
              )}
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  
    
    );
};


export default App;
```

and here is App.cs which is my table design :

```
.app-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 2rem;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 250%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

th {
  background-color: rgb(117, 201, 250);
}

td {
  background-color: rgb(205, 235, 253);
}

form {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

form td:last-child {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

form * {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

I try to change som but it not even close to the design i want. I want to know how to make my table design like that or is there some other way or did i need to use different method of makin table?.

Comment: here you go: https://codepen.io/dinh/pen/ZEbNMjO Just search `tailwind table` on codepen.io en you'll find tons of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With tailwind, you juste have to set `classNames` and you'll find classes on the [Tailwind doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration).

For example :

- on the `<div className="app-container">` ou could add classes `p-5` to add a padding.
- on `<table>` add `className="rounded-lg border-none shadow-xl"`
- etc etc